# what is the uniform type identifier for docx file

Tags: ios5, uti

Read the document of [*Developer Library*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html), the identifier for *doc* is "**com.microsoft.word.doc**". But what is the identifier for *docx*??

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The identifier is `org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document`.